# Extendable Markdown parser in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, markdown

I'm looking to redo/update a webpage of mine ([Klingonska Akademien](http://klingonska.org/)) to bring it up to speed with what has been happing with HTML and CSS the last ten years or so. :) In my research this far I've concluded that I probably want to use [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) so I'm thinking I might as well stick to Ruby as much as possible.

That being said, I need an *extendable* Markdown parser. I've had a look at [Redcarpet](https://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet), but it seems that only the *renderer* side of thing is extendable, not the parser (understandable with their security and speed requirements—but speed isn't all that important to *me*). So I can't add my own markup.

Now I already have tons of texts on the Klingon Language that I want to reuse, in which `{...}` mark text in Klingon, and `<...>` mark translations thereof. I'd like this rendered as `<b lang="tlh">...</b>` and `<i class="transl">...</i>` in HTML output, but I also need to further process the content of `{...}` to insert hyphenation points.

Does there exist a Ruby-based Markdown parser where one can add own markup in this way?

If not, is there a parser which could pretty easily be modified to do this? (For me that would mean: well writted/documented code, and written in Ruby only.)

Comment: Take a look at nanoc - it does process erb first, then markdown. You could also define your own filter.

Comment: +1'd because you are parsing Klingon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/). It has a lot of advantages over Redcarpet but I'm using second one due it is very fast. But sometimes Kramdown is better option.

Comment: Link isn't responding for me, try https://kramdown.gettalong.org/ instead.

Comment: By the way, it seems Kramdown has ['extensions'](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#extensions) in the sense of *additions* to markdown syntax. But, unless I'm missing something, there seems to be no way to add new syntax.